# Windows 10 Pro Retail version on VM, Can I move it?

Tags: windows

I bought a Win 10 Pro retail version. Installed it on a VM on computer #1. I want to move the VM to computer #2 for a few months, then I'll want to move it to computer #3. Can I do that license wise?

Thanks

Back story if anybody cares: My 4 year old Macbook Air was clinging to life by it's fingernails, it finally died. I bought Win 10 and installed it as VM on my Wife's newer Air. I just put a new logic board in my Old Air and want to move the Win 10 to it. If Apple ever actually releases the new Macbook Pros I'll be getting one of them and would like to transfer the VM and license a 3rd time... :)

Comment: What does this question have to do with the VMS family of operating systems? Perhaps you should remove the `vms` tag.

Comment: Done, thank for catching that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do this licence wise so long as you never have it installed on one computer at once, the windows 10 licence agreement states that you may move it from one machine to another as long as it is never installed on more than one at once.